# Titan strange consistency issues - Multiple edges with same edge id

Tags: cassandra, titan, eventual-consistency

We are using **Titan 1.0.0** with **Cassandra version 3.9.0-1**, from **datastax-ddc** on CentOs-7 system. We are seeing some strange issues, like:

- Multiple edges with the same edge id, few properties on these edge do differ in values.

  g.V().has('msid', 6171699).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e',153).as('e')inV().has('msid',58713376).select('e')
  ==>e[**54ekdatm-1lezwb4-45cl-195s9km8**][3471761488-prio_child->98305011872]
  ==>e[**54ekdatm-1lezwb4-45cl-195s9km8**][3471761488-prio_child->98305011872]
- Getting more results, after applying more restrictions

  g.V().has('msid', 6171699).outE('prio_child').count()
  ==>**60**

  g.V().has('msid', 6171699).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e, 153).count()
  ==>**66**

I have even tried setting ConsistencyModifier.LOCK, as suggested by Titan Documentation [Eventually Consistent Backends](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/eventual-consistency.html#_data_consistency), but it has not helped. I am still getting arbitrary results.

Answer (score 7):

Titan 1.0.0 is not compatible with Cassandra 3.x http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html

Titan is also no longer being maintained. JanusGraph http://janusgraph.org/ has taken up where Titan left off and is being updated and maintained actively.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce and fix it, by following [Data Consistency](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/eventual-consistency.html#_data_consistency). I was missing the following the command after setting the ConsistencyModifier.

```
mgmt.commit()
```

Following is the piece of code which reproduced the problem, with both the versions of cassandra i.e. cassandra 2.1.x and cassandra 3.9.x.

```
    TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open("/opt/cmsgraph/config/edgepoc.conf");
    try {
        int parent = -2128958273;
        int child = 58541705;
        int hostid = 83;
        int numThreads = 100;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];
        for(int i =0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new EdgeUpdator(graph, parent, child, hostid));
        }
        for(int i =0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            threads[i].start();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    } finally {
        graph.close();
    }

    private static class EdgeUpdator implements Runnable {
        public EdgeUpdator(TitanGraph graph, int parent, int child, int hostid) {
            this.graph = graph;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.child = child;
            this.hostid = hostid;
        }

        private int parent;
        private int child;
        private int hostid;
        private TitanGraph graph;

        public void run() {
            TitanTransaction trxn = graph.newTransaction();
            GraphTraversalSource g = trxn.traversal();
            Edge edge = (Edge)g.V().has("msid", parent).outE("prio_child").has("hostid_e", hostid).as("e").inV().has("msid", child).select("e").next();
            Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
            edge.property("updatedAt_e", random.nextLong());
            edge.property("plrank", random.nextInt());
            trxn.commit();
        }
    }
```

Before executing the the above code. I see:

```
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e', 83).as('e').inV().has('msid', 58541705).select('e')
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e', 83).as('e').inV().has('msid', 58541705).select('e').count()
    ==>1
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e', 83).count()
    ==>104
```

After executing the code, I see:

```
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e', 83).as('e').inV().has('msid', 58541705).select('e')
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    ==>e[239suvpz-17ofqw-41ed-9eutzq8][73363640-prio_child->20489355296]
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e', 83).as('e').inV().has('msid', 58541705).select('e').count()
    ==>10
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e', 83).as('e').inV().has('msid', 58541705).select('e').dedup().count()
    ==>1
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').has('hostid_e', 83).count()
    ==>113
    gremlin> g.V().has('msid', -2128958273).outE('prio_child').count()
    ==>104
```

After applying the ConsitencyModifier.LOCK to "prio_child" edge, I observed that 9 of the 10 threads failed with following exception and, I it didn't result in any multiple edges with same edge id problem.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.FastNoSuchElementException
```

Following is the exact changes I made:

```
    mgmt = graph.openManagement()
    prio_child=mgmt.getRelationType('prio_child')
    mgmt.setConsistency(prio_child, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK)
    mgmt.commit()
```

Comment: Even this has not helped and the problem still exists. The **ConsistencyModifier.LOCK** is **NOT** working as expected. Basically after digging down the issue further, I found that it's the case of VertexCentric Index corruption. After dropping all the custom vertex centric  (Titan also creates a default vertex centric index for all the edge properties automatically - which work fine), this problem was resolved.

Comment: Opened an [issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/301) with JanusGraph. Basically the VertexCentric indices are getting corrupt here, If the index doesn't come into picture correct results are being returned.